# Custom types across multiple .ts/.tsx files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to build up my first project with Typescript (and React/Redux) and struggling to pass my custom types between multiple files: like making my action types available to action creators, reducer, and each component dispatching some of those actions.

So, what's the proper approach here:

- declare all the custom types in a common file and import that wherever necessary?
- declare custom types in their related files and make the web of imports/exports?
- some other option that didn't yet cross my mind?

I understand that this question may be closed as rather opinionated, but I failed to find the answer neither in typescriptlang.org nor in the other resources (including SO topics).

Comment: I always went for #2, but I am also open for some good other view points.

Comment: #2 has the additional benefit of making dependencies between files explicit. Note that you already have the "web of imports/exports" right now but it's implicit and people who read the code are unaware of it - making comprehension and refactoring harder.

Comment: I prefer #1, I think each thing has its place, its even better because sometimes you need some really complex typing and isn't necessary people that look at your component know how it works, they just need to use it. 

Use in another file is helpful too because allow the interpreter not to interpret all the content, bringing the intellisense and typing errors faster.

Of course this is only for scoped types of a component or a module, thing more "global" should be placed on specific folders like `types`, `interfaces` or `enums`.

Comment: I prefer #1 as if I need to look for my types or make a change, I know where to go. I just import the types that I need from that module. Might also be worth mentioning that the Typescript project itself uses a single `types.ts` file. If you reuse types a lot, makes sense to keep them in a common file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually split my types depending upon if they are more global or local. For example, if I have some types that are only used within a single module or file, I will tend to store those types in the same place as the implementation:

```
/components
  /Search
    /Search.tsx
    /search.types.ts <- contains component types like props
    /SearchContainer.tsx
```

For more global types, I have a separate `/types` folder, usually at the root level that I split into separate namespaces.

```
/types
  /search
  /authentication
  /actions
  /routing
```

What you store in this `types` directory will be specific to your application, but you get the general idea. You can also use aliasing to import types so that you don't have to deal with relative imports up many levels: `../../../types/something` => `@types/something`

Comment: aliasing is a good idea but not an option for people building a distributable library

Comment: I was guessing that it has to be something hybrid. Thanks for the clues.

Comment: That seems to be the separate question, however, I'd appreciate slight hint from you: is *alias trick* supposed to be implemented in some way [like that](https://dev.to/larswaechter/path-aliases-with-typescript-in-nodejs-4353)?

Comment: @ZChu It definitely depends on your build setup and your specific needs, but yes that is a good way to achieve the aliasing

Answer (score 1):

place all of your types into a module and call `filename.d.ts`

```
//filename.d.ts

  declare module "my-module"{
    
      export type int = number;
    
    
    {
```

if you want to use enum  place it on `.ts` file (not `d.ts`)